# Is there a way to get the length of an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map over an array of objects to get the following structure:

```
[
  {
    media:'Wall Street Journal', 
    informational: 101, 
    negative, 296, 
    balanced: length of the array, 
    positive: length of the array
  }
 ]
```

Here is an example of one of the 67 arrays I'm trying to map:

```
[
  "Wall Street Journal",
  {
    "Informational": Array(101),
    "Negative": Array(296),
    "Balanced": [
      {
        "correspondent_1": "Anthony Richard Harrup",
        "correspondent_2": "False",
        "date": "1-January-2016",
        "date_object": "2016-01-01",
        "day_number": 1,
        "front_page": "False"
      },
      {
        "correspondent_1": "Anthony Richard Harrup",
        "correspondent_2": "False",
        "date": "1-January-2016",
        "date_object": "2016-01-01",
        "day_number": 1,
        "front_page": "False"
      }
    ],

    "Positive": [
      {
        "correspondent_1": "Anthony Richard Harrup",
        "correspondent_2": "False",
        "date": "1-January-2016",
        "date_object": "2016-01-01",
        "day_number": 1,
        "front_page": "False"
      },
      {
        "correspondent_1": "Anthony Richard Harrup",
        "correspondent_2": "False",
        "date": "1-January-2016",
        "date_object": "2016-01-01",
        "day_number": 1,
        "front_page": "False"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I left the array information on purpose as this is the result I'm getting from the console. I wrote two examples of how the array looks like when you click on the arrow in the console and it even gives you the length property back. When I try to map over this array to get the structure I previously mentioned, it's giving me back that it cannot read the property length of undefined but it seems that it is there. I even tried the same code on another part of my project and it worked there.

Here is my map function:

```
  const data = mediaValues.map(function(media) {
    return {
      media: media[0],
      positive: media[1].Positive.length,
      negative: media[1].Negative.length,
      balanced: media[1].Balanced.length,
      informational: media[1].Informational.length,
    };
  });
  console.log(data);
```

If I use only the media it gives me back the name of the newspaper, if I use media[1].Positive it gives me back the information with all the objects, the same goes for all the other categories, but when I try to access the length function it's not working. I just want to get the total number of entries that my array has for each category.

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Remember that "it's not working" is an opinion, not an error (after all, the code is doing exactly what it should be doing, that's literally all it _can_ do) So: what did you expect it to do, and what did it do instead? Are you getting console errors? What _does_ happen when your code hits those `.length` instructions?

Comment: Hi Mike, unfortunately I cannot upload photos in order to share the output of the console.log(). But it is basically saying: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I used the same code in another part of the project to get the amount of positive, negative, balanced and informational news per month and it worked there. I replicated the code but now I cannot figure out what the problem is

Comment: Where does that array come from? Are you making an ajax request, or a database lookup, or something like that? Mistakes in coding around asynchronous APIs are an extremely common cause of problems that fit this description.

Comment: It feels like you did not take the [tour], and did not read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask)... the console error is normal text, you can copy and paste that into your question just fine, using [code formatting](/editing-help) to make sure it shows property. The error is pretty clear: you're calling `.length` on a variable that has nothing in it. So: reduce your code and start finding out which variable that is. It's probably `media[1]` so: find out what's in that.

Comment: @AlonsoAg - *nor should you*. Copy the text and upload that. *NEVER* upload pictures of text - paste the text itself.

Comment: So, `mediaValues` is an array containing many elements like the one you showed?

Comment: Hi Pointy, I'm reading a csv with d3.

Comment: Hi Anis. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This is the output of the console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at tendency.js:416
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at outlets (tendency.js:413)
    at tendency.js:29

Comment: Sorry Mike, I'm trying to be as clear as possible, I studied Political Science so I'm new to the whole coding world. If you have any advice on how to ask a "good question" I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check index of your media in your loopl like this

```
const data = mediaValues.map(function(media,index) {

  if(index==1){
    return {
      positive: media.Positive.length,
      negative: media.Negative.length,
      balanced: media.Balanced.length,
      informational: media.Informational.length,    };
  }else{
  return {
  mediia:media
  }
  }

  });
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @Orgil ! I tried your code but it didn't work. It's still saying the following: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at tendency.js:428
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at outlets (tendency.js:425)
    at tendency.js:29

Comment: if it's answering your question mark as correct answer :)